# Bold text changes alignment of surrounding text?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple navigation, and show the active clicked tab bold.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav>
    <li><a href="#">Tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tab2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tab3</a></li>
</ul>
```

The clicked tab will always get the `class="active"`.

```
li.active a {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Problem: The size of the tabtext somehow changes a bit when I click it due to the bold font, cause the tabs beneath to move 1-2px.

Question: how can I prevent this?

When I use `font-weight: normal`, then these movements are gone. So they are definitely caused by the bold font. But how can I force the nonclicked tab-texts to no move?

Comment: Define a height for the list items.

Comment: why don't you try with `font-wight:700` instead of `font-weight:bold`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `bold` will change the increase the amount of pixels required to render the text, i.e. bold text is bigger than normal text - even though the `font-size` is unaffected. This change will push the surrounding elements.

You can either not use bold or there are various methods available to prevent the text shifting by 'reserving the space', e.g.

[Inline elements shifting when made bold on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556153/horiz-css-menu-text-shifting-on-bold-hover)

[change of font-weight to bold is unwantingly changing width of element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650360/change-of-font-weight-to-bold-is-unwantingly-changing-width-of-element)